# Google Cloud Build gsutil with python entrypoint

Tags: python, google-cloud-build, gsutil

I want to use a python script to download several files from Google Storage by calling `gsutil` via `subprocess.check_call()` inside the Python script during a Cloud Build step.

Therefore, I use the following step inside the `cloudbuild.yaml`:

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: ['-c',
         'pip install google-cloud-storage && python /path_to_script/script.py --arg1 $_ARG1 --arg2 $TAG_NAME --arg3 $BRANCH_NAME --arg4 $_ARG4'
  ]
```

But Cloud Build throws a strange `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` Python error. I can run the same Python script with the same arguments locally **as well as** by using `python:3.7-sim` inside Cloud Build with that SyntaxError:

```
- name: 'python:3.7-slim'
  entrypoint: /bin/sh
  args: ['-c',
         'pip install google-cloud-storage && python python /path_to_script/script.py --arg1 $_ARG1 --arg2 $TAG_NAME --arg3 $BRANCH_NAME --arg4 $_ARG4'
  ]
```

The later example is working until `gsutil` is called, because it is not part of the `python:3.7-slim` container (therefor expected behavior).

Any helping comments on why `gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil` is throwing that error? Is the entrypoint wrongly specified?

Comment: What are you doing in your script?

Comment: The script pulls a list of all files in the bucket and filters them according to some user input (using substitution variables in cloud build). Then, the files are downloaded to the current workspace in cloud build.
Interestingly, the scripts breaks right at the beginning within the function definition. As said before, the scripts itself runs locally as well as within the python:3.7-slim container.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. That's why I would like to understand the special thing that you do to fail. If you have a minimal code to reproduce the issue, it's perfect!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an easier solution by invoking the dedicated `gsutil` image in combination with wildcards to accomplish a similar filtering as in the python script.
See simplified example below:

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
  - '-c'
  - |
    gsutil -m cp -r 'gs://bucket/*/' '/workspace'
```

This actually does the job for me pretty well.